# Error: Hook failed with error code 1:

Tags: android, node.js, npm, ionic-framework

I am working on an IONIC Project,

while I am adding android platform, it gives me an error like this.

```
Error: Hook failed with error code 1: D:\IONIC Workspace\risecx-app\hooks\before_prepare\01_jshint.js
    at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:195:23
    at _rejected (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:797:24)
    at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:741:41)
    at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
    at flush (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:417:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:346:13)
```

my hooks\before_prepare\01_jshint.js file is like...

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var jshint = require('jshint').JSHINT;
var async = require('async');

var foldersToProcess = [ 'js', 'js/services' ];

foldersToProcess.forEach(function(folder) {
        processFiles("www/" + folder);
});

function processFiles(dir, callback) {
        var errorCount = 0;
        fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
                if (err) {
                        console.log('processFiles err: ' + err);
                        return;
                }
                async.eachSeries(list, function(file, innercallback) {
                        file = dir + '/' + file;
                        fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
                                if(!stat.isDirectory()) {
                                        if(path.extname(file) === ".js") {
                                                lintFile(file, function(hasError) {
                                                        if(hasError) {
                                                                errorCount++;
                                                        }
                                                        innercallback();
                                                });
                                        } else {
                                                innercallback();
                                        }
                                } else {
                                        innercallback();
                                }
                        });
                }, function(error) {
                        if(errorCount > 0) {
                                process.exit(1);
                        }
                });
        });
}

function lintFile(file, callback) {
        console.log("Linting " + file);
        fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
                if(err) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + err);
                        return;
                }
                if(jshint(data.toString())) {
                        console.log('File ' + file + ' has no errors.');
                        console.log('-----------------------------------------');
                        callback(false);
                } else {
                        console.log('Errors in file ' + file);
                        var out = jshint.data(),
                        errors = out.errors;
                        for(var j = 0; j < errors.length; j++) {
                                console.log(errors[j].line + ':' + errors[j].character + ' -> ' + errors[j].reason + ' -> ' +
errors[j].evidence);
                        }
                        console.log('-----------------------------------------');
                        callback(true); 
                }
        });
}
```

I have worked with following commands....

> npm install jshint --save
>
> npm install q --save
>
> npm install async

so any idea, where I am making a mistake....

Comment: which o.s you are using?

Comment: update your jshint using command npm update jshint and update everything(Cordova, Ionic CLI, Ionic Lib)

Comment: I am working on Windows 7 @Muhsin

Comment: lets chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95769/ionic-installation-problem

Comment: Thanks @Mushin but I am traveling now and not at office today, we will chat on monday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check  your  `hooks directory` have execute permissions.Give all permission to hooks and it's child folders

Answer (score 6):

Just delete your hooks directory and type this command.

`ionic hooks add`

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It also fails with error code 1 if you have a mistake in any of your files.  Check to make sure it hasn't told you about any errors in you files before that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I created an after_prepare hook to override cordova build process to use the actual versionCode specified in config.xml. I had the same error.
I solved it by adding "**#!/usr/bin/env node**" in my hook file(**without quotes**) at the top.That resolved everything. Hope it may help you .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Moodle Mobile 2 build returning this error - I was missing the 'node_modules' folder from the main directory for the build to complete.
Hope this helps